# Angular proper use case for router-outlets

Tags: angular, router-outlet

When am I supposed to use router outlets? Obviously I have 1 in my app.component but what are some other use cases?

It seemed like a good idea to place 1 in my user component `(user/:id)` to show a post list `(user/:id/posts)` but then there seems to be no way to inject the `user.posts` data into the outlet making this a bad idea in my opinion.

I'd love to hear some thoughts about this.

Edit: This post is specificly about how the router-outlet is unable to recieve data directly and therfor kinda defeats its own purpose in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>` is essentially a directive that is exposed from `@angular/router`. In our `Routes` configuration, we specify the `path` and the `component` that is expected to be loaded when that path is reached.

But Angular doesn't know where it should inject that Component template. That's something that we tell Angular by specifying the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

Essentially, it acts as the container area for the Components that are supposed to be loaded via routing.

Where do you put it completely depends on the sort of routing config that you have in place.

In case of child routes, if you want to specify Components that would again be loaded based on routing, then you can specify a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in that Parent Route Component as well.

Take a look at this `Routes` config for eg:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent, canActivate: [ ActivateGuard ] },
  { path: 'messages', component: MessageListComponent, canDeactivate: [ DeactivateGuard ] },
  { path: 'parent', component: ParentComponent },
  { path: 'bd', component: BuiltInDirectivesComponent },
  { path: 'cd', component: CustomDirectivesComponent },
  { path: 'new-user', component: NewUserComponent },
  { path: 'new-user-reactive', component: NewUserReactiveComponent },
  { 
    path: 'users', 
    component: UsersComponent,
    children: [
      { path: ':userId', component: UserDetailsComponent },
      { path: '', component: PlaceholderComponent }
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Now say if I want to show a List of Users for the `UsersComponent` and that too on the left. And on the right, I need to show the details of a selected user from the list.

In this case, there would be one `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the `AppComponent` Template. And then there would be another `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the `UsersComponent` Template. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: I understand what it does. What I don't understand is why you can't pass data to router-outlets when its so obvious that they need data. In your example the UserDetailsComponent will load without any user data and has to fetch it eventhough his parent has all the data he needs.

Comment: Who said you can't? What you're looking for is a [`Resolve`](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)

Comment: What do you mean by **fetch again**? If that means making an API call, not necessarily. As in the Resolver, you could inject your shared service as a dependency which already has the data.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about shared services and will try to find some information about it.